# Gazebo IR sensor

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there any IR proximity sensor model/plugin for Gazebo?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/166236/gazebo-ir-sensor/) by [z.xing](https://answers.ros.org/users/17796/z.xing/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-05-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do you mean an IR camera, an IR proximity sensor, or an IR motion sensor?

For the first and third, Gazebo would need to have some model of IR spectrum (which it doesn't). For the second, the plugin mentioned here might do the trick:

- http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/5303/is-there-a-gazebo-plugin-that-simulates-sonar-and/
- https://github.com/pal-robotics/pal_gazebo_plugins

---

Originally posted by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) with karma: 5809 on 2014-05-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [z.xing](https://answers.ros.org/users/17796/z.xing/) on 2014-05-17**:
I meant proximity sensor. I checked the links before, but I thought it's using laser instead of IR, could you please clarify it a little bit for me? I'm new to robotics so please forgive me for the naive questions. Thanks a lot!